# is there a way for one Akka node to know if the other akka node got restarted

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have a akka node (say A) which does the bootstrapping and once done sends a message to other akka Node (say B), only then Node B will start doing its job. Now the problem is, say Node A sent bootstrapping message to Node B and then Node B got restarted, so when Node B came up it will be in waiting state (waiting for Bootstrapping msg from Node A).

Is there a way Node A know that Node B got restarted and sends the message again?

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions FYI.

1) You can let nodeB send one message to nodeA every time when it starts by using `actorSelection`. Then nodeA can know nodeB start.

2) Set `event listener` on nodeA.

```
object ClusterDomainEventListener {
  def props = Props[ClusterDomainEventListener]
  val name = "clusterDomainEventListener"
}

class ClusterDomainEventListener extends Actor {
  Cluster(context.system).subscribe(self, classOf[ClusterDomainEvent])

  def receive = {
    case MemberUp(m) =>
      println(m.address)
  }
}
```

NodeA:

```
system.actorOf(ClusterDomainEventListener.props, ClusterDomainEventListener.name)
```

Then, every time nodeB start, nodeA will get the `MemberUp` event, the println output is: `akka.tcp://YourActorSystemName@10.192.225.19:2551`, you surely know nodeB is for example run on `10.192.225.18:2559`, so you can know B is up. This is a little hard coding.

3) If you can set a role to nodeB akka configure file:

```
cluster {
  roles = ["nodeB"]

  seed-nodes = [
    "akka.tcp://YourActorSystemName@10.192.225.18:2551"
  ]
}
```

then you can reuse method 2, but in `case MemberUp(m)`, you can just use `if (m.hasRole("nodeB"))` to know B is up, and do next things you want.